# Swapped screenshot shortcuts between file and clipboard not working as intended

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, live-usb, clipboard, screenshot

So for my convenience, I swapped the shortcuts for saving screenshot file and saving to clipboard as follows because I rarely need the file:

[image]

The problem with this is that Print and Shift+Print now do nothing, while all others (including Alt+Print, which I used for pasting here) work as intended.

If anybody knows a way to force these shortcuts to work properly, please let me know. I'm kinda new to Linux in general, but I come from a technological background so I'm not afraid of getting my hands dirty.

This is a persistent live USB Ubuntu 20 on an external hard drive I've been playing with for a few months already for maybe fully migrating my operations to Linux in the near future. I want my mistakes to happen here and not after I moved :)

Edit: just so you don't simply close this as a duplicate, I did check other similar questions but they seem to be using a command line instead of the shortcut or settings interface and some seem to have it working but the clipboard is cleared afterwards. In my case, not even the screenshot flash and area selection happens. It's like as if the shortcut isn't triggering anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why or how, but this time, going the Windows route of restarting the OS solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is an issue with the dialog. Try changing these keys through the command line as:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot "['<Ctrl>Print']"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot-clip "['Print']"
```

Undo these changes by using `reset` instead of `set`, and leaving out the last argument.

Comment: turns out I just had to restart the OS. I turned it on today to see if your solution would work and it's already working without it. But thank you for the help